# How can I view django home page outside my server

Tags: python, django

I have just installed django with python 2.7. After creating intitial project it says to check at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

But that is my VPS server and i can't open browser there.

i tried  `http://vpsIPaddress:8000` but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start your server in development mode, it is ONLY available via `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`. That said, if you have a port conflict, you can change the port it uses:

```
python manage.py runserver 12345
```

And then you can access the development server via:

```
http://127.0.0.1:12345
```

It's worth reiterating that the development server will NOT be available from remote hosts, to discourage you from using it in a production environment, which it is not suited for. If you need to be able to access your Django app from a remote host, you need to deploy your application to something like [Apache2](http://httpd.apache.org/) with [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

Comment: I know its not production safe but there should be some way of doing that . can't i assign the VPS IP in some config file

Comment: @bidu: No.  You can't.  It's done on the command line for a reason.  The reason is because this is for development **only**.  Nothing else.

Comment: @S.Lott I searched from internet and i tried this `/opt/python27/bin/python manage.py runserver 212.xx.xx.xx:8000` and it worked. Is there any problem with that, i mean any security issue. I am newbie so i don't know any low level issues

Comment: @bidu: This is for development **only**.  Nothing else. It's very, very slow, completely useless for multiple, concurrent connections (since it's single-threaded) and probably insecure because you're running on your development computer which is rarely configured correctly for production. Please **read** the Django documentation.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/

Comment: Thanks Lott , i know what do u mean

Comment: This answer doesn't help if you are using docker containers. The answer provided below by Xiao is what helped me.

Answer (score 17):

You can start your server with following command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:12345
```

Then, the dev server will bind all the possible ip address on your server which is a convenient way for test :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - some rules were meant to be broken.

Comment: This is a much more helpful answer, especially if you are using Docker containers where even in a test environment your client can be a remote host.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue while running my server using python development server. After reading the answer, I almost was going to switch to nginx. Someone on the web I saw that your can

```
python manage.py runserver example.com:8000
```

you can also put the ip address instead of the host name. This works. I just tested it.